# Is there an IBAN for US banks?

Tags: united-states, banking, iban

Do US banks have an IBAN number? I'm trying to wire money through my Bank’s website and they’re asking for the IBAN. Is there one for US banks? And if not what do I do?

Comment: This is one of the currently infuriating things on the planet, that US banks are low-tech.

Comment: @Fattie: Low-tech US banks may be, but that's not the reason that ACH routing numbers and IBAN numbers aren't interchangeable.

Comment: Ben, I just meant "it's infuriating they do not (often) have IBANs"

Answer (score 8):

US has not adopted IBAN. It is only European Union and few other countries. See the relevant [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number).

You just need to give the ABA code (bank code) with account number

Comment: Not Australia, but there are some non-European countries especially in the Middle East and Africa which use it (to various degrees).

Comment: @chirlu Thanks for pointing out. I some how recall (incorrectly?) Australia and New Zealand being early adaptors along with EU

Comment: Is "ABA code" the same as "routing number"?

Comment: @RonJohn yes it is same.

Comment: @Dheer For a complete and authoritative list, check the article about the [SEPA](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/integration/retail/sepa/html/index.en.html) (Single Euro Payment Area) on the website of the European Central Bank.

Comment: @Dheer As far as I know my NZ bank account does not have an IBAN. There is a [similar number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_bank_account_number) used to send money within NZ, just like IBAN.